# Something went wrong with network provider?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, dependency-injection

I've got this error below. Also when i have no errors, my network provider doesnt work. May someone know how to resolve this prob, which i have many days before.I've tried some things from youtube videos, but still doesnt work. Anywhere some people say that is an error with ionic 4

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for NetworkService: (?, ?, ?).
        at syntaxError (compiler.js:486)
        at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:15706)
        at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:15541)
        at CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata (compiler.js:15521)
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (compiler.js:15881)
        at compiler.js:15792
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (compiler.js:15752)
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15320)
        at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:34413)
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import { NativeGeocoder, NativeGeocoderReverseResult, NativeGeocoderForwardResult, NativeGeocoderOptions } from '@ionic-native/native-geocoder';
import { GoogleMap, GoogleMaps } from '@ionic-native/google-maps';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { IzvjestajPage } from '../pages/izvjestaj/izvjestaj';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { NalogPage } from '../pages/nalog/nalog';
import { OtkazPage } from '../pages/otkaz/otkaz';
import { ServicesPage } from '../pages/services/services';
import { RegistrationPage } from '../pages/registration/registration';
import { PeopleServiceProvider } from '../providers/people-service/people-service';
import { LocationAccuracy } from '@ionic-native/location-accuracy';
import { ExtendedDeviceInformation } from '@ionic-native/extended-device-information';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import { NetworkService } from '../providers/network/network';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    LoginPage,
    IzvjestajPage,
    NalogPage,
    OtkazPage,
    ServicesPage,
    RegistrationPage


  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()



  ],

  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    LoginPage,
    IzvjestajPage,
    NalogPage,
    OtkazPage,
    ServicesPage,
    RegistrationPage

  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    HttpClientModule,
    Geolocation,
    NativeGeocoder,
    GoogleMaps,
    StatusBar,
    LocationAccuracy,
    NetworkService,



    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    PeopleServiceProvider,


  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

network.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ToastController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

export enum ConnectionStatus {
  Online,
  Offline
}

//@Injectable({
//  providedIn: 'root'
//})
export class NetworkService {

  private status: BehaviorSubject<ConnectionStatus> = new BehaviorSubject(ConnectionStatus.Offline);

  constructor(private network: Network, private toastController: ToastController, private plt: Platform) {
    this.plt.ready().then(() => {
      this.initializeNetworkEvents();
      let status = this.network.type !== 'none' ? ConnectionStatus.Online : ConnectionStatus.Offline;
      this.status.next(status);
    });
  }

  public initializeNetworkEvents() {

    this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
      if (this.status.getValue() === ConnectionStatus.Online) {
        console.log('WE ARE OFFLINE');
        this.updateNetworkStatus(ConnectionStatus.Offline);
      }
    });

    this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
      if (this.status.getValue() === ConnectionStatus.Offline) {
        console.log('WE ARE ONLINE');
        this.updateNetworkStatus(ConnectionStatus.Online);
      }
    });
  }

  private async updateNetworkStatus(status: ConnectionStatus) {
    this.status.next(status);

    let connection = status == ConnectionStatus.Offline ? 'Offline' : 'Online';
    console.log('test');
    let toast = this.toastController.create({
      message: `You are now ${connection}`,
      duration: 3000,
      position: 'bottom'
    }).present();
  };

  public onNetworkChange(): Observable<ConnectionStatus> {
    return this.status.asObservable();
  }

  public getCurrentNetworkStatus(): ConnectionStatus {
    return this.status.getValue();
  }
}
```

Comment: One issue i see i you did not add Network plugin into app module’s provider list.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is basically saying that Angular's Dependency Injection can't work out what objects that constructor (of `NetworkService`) wants. So you could remove the parameters from the constructor (if they aren't needed), or you need to make sure you have all objects registered with the DI.

Your `NetworkService`'s only constructor has multiple parameters, but you don't specify how `app.module` is supposed to inject them...so I'm guessing one of those parameter's types is wrong.  e.g. there's no obvious `ToastController` in `app.module`.

Alternatively you might just need a parameter-less constructor in `NetworkService`.

Specifically for your `NetworkService` code, your constructor is doing more than building the object, I would consider just leaving the `let status...` line in and move that platform stuff to a seperate `init` function.

Comment: i've been added ToastController in appmoduel imports, but error is still here. :/

Comment: Well keep going, the message is basically saying that Angular's Dependency Injection can't work out what objects that constructor wants.  So you could remove the parameters from the constructor (if they aren't needed), or you need to make sure you have all objects registered with the DI.

Comment: Just taken another look at your code, I think you might need to look at rearranging it, the constructor is doing more than creating the object.  I think it needs to just set a default status, and move that platform stuff out to a separate init function.